# Match documents which do not match pairs of fields

Tags: mongodb

I have documents with `a`, and `b` fields (and some other extra fields). I have a list of pairs of values for `a`, `b,` fields and I would like to match all MongoDB documents which do not have their `a` and `b` fields be the same as any pair of those fields in the given list. So if my documents in the MongoDB database are:

```
{a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
{a: 4, b: 5, c: 6}
{a: 7, b: 8, c: 9}
{a: 1, b: 8, c: 10}
```

And my list is `[{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 7, b: 8}]`, I would like to make a query which would return only the second and the last documents.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **[`$nor`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/query/nor/#op._S_nor)** operator in your query which performs a logical NOR operation on an array of one or more query expression and selects the documents that fail all the query expressions in the array:

```
var arr = [{a: 1, b: 2}, {a: 7, b: 8}];
db.test.find({ "$nor": arr });
```

Comment: But this will not match pair-wise? Document with `{a: 1, b: 8}` will also not be matched, but it should be.

Comment: Hard to really follow your requirements clearly, you mention _I would like to match all MongoDB documents which do not have their a and b fields be the same as any pair of those fields in the given list._ the above query does just that. Now if you introduce the doc `{a: 1, b: 8}` this negates your above requirement, can you be a little bit more specific by including as many test cases?

Comment: Ah, in that case the **`$nor`** operator is what you are after; I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Following will filter documents which has any of the defined values

```
db.<your_colllection>.find({
    $and : [
        {$and: [{a :{$ne: 1}},{b: {$ne: 2}}]},
        {$and: [{a :{$ne: 7}},{b: {$ne: 8}}]}
    ]
})
```

Following will filter documents which has the defined **paired** values

```
db.delme.find({
    $nor : [
        {$nor: [{a :{$ne: 1}},{b: {$ne: 2}}]},
        {$nor: [{a :{$ne: 7}},{b: {$ne: 8}}]}
    ]
})
```

Comment: You do not really need the inner `$and`, no?
    $and : [
        {a :{$ne: 1}, b: {$ne: 2}},
        {a :{$ne: 7}, b: {$ne: 8}},
    ]

Comment: You are right, it not filtering based on pairs, but filtering out documents having any of those values defined. Updated the answer which should filter the documents based on the pairs